# Showing polygon on cesiumJs

Tags: polygon, cesium

I'm trying to show polygon on cesiumJs, like the sample which is demonstrated: https://cesium.com/learn/cesiumjs-learn/cesiumjs-creating-entities/

I used this code:

```js
const viewer = new Cesium.Viewer("cesiumContainer");

const wyoming = viewer.entities.add({
    polygon: {
        hierarchy: Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegreesArray([
            -109.080842, 45.002073,
            -105.91517, 45.002073,
            -104.058488, 44.996596,
            -104.053011, 43.002989,
            -104.053011, 41.003906,
            -105.728954, 40.998429,
            -107.919731, 41.003906,
            -109.04798, 40.998429,
            -111.047063, 40.998429,
            -111.047063, 42.000709,
            -111.047063, 44.476286,
            -111.05254, 45.002073,
        ]),
        height: 0,
        material: Cesium.Color.RED.withAlpha(0.5),
        outline: true,
        outlineColor: Cesium.Color.BLACK,
    },
});

viewer.zoomTo(wyoming);
```

But I just see the globe (default viewer of cesium).
I tried to set access token and nothing changed in result.
Can any one offer a hint what the problem is?

Comment: Hi, I tried pasting your code into [Cesium Sandcastle](https://sandcastle.cesium.com/) and it seems to work fine there.  Can you describe how to reproduce the problem?

Comment: yes exactly, the code work fine in sandcastle, bet when i try to run code on editor i just see simple globe which is simple:
const viewer = new Cesium.Viewer("cesiumContainer")
the problem is not about access token or my html and css files, i run some code before and it work properly
but in this part of code when i run on editor i just see simple globe, and not zooming or selecting polygon